# Internet Problems ( This site cant be reached )

Tags: internet, firewall

I have a problem in connecting to some websites. For example, Google, Gmail, Yahoo websites have no problem. but I am not able to open websites like askubuntu, nvidia, facebook. Kindly please help me to solve this issue.

Here is a pic for a better understanding of my issue.
[image]

Comment: We're going to need more information that you're providing. What version of Ubuntu are you running? When you say "some webbsites [sic]", can you include some sites that do work? If at least one site works, then we--at least--know that you're network connection is functional (one less variable to consider in troubleshooting your issue).

Comment: Are you behind a proxy (possibly filtering your access)?

Comment: Via browser? Just one browser or multiple? Do you have plugins installed, maybe JS disabled? Firefox used to have a 'start without plugins' mode. Try that.

Comment: Have you tried pinging any of the domains that do not work? For example: `ping askubuntu.com`.